# excel nested vlookup function using formats and NA Arguments

Tags: excel, function, nested, vlookup

I placed an example below, of which I don't necessarily 'need' to work, but I don't like that I can't get it to work.  I've attempted to use the ISNA function, but am having little success since I

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(H3,Credit!H:J,3,FALSE)=(J3*-1),"Please Purge",IF(VLOOKUP(H3,Credit!H:J,3,FALSE)<(J3*-1),"Not enough Credit... research",IF(VLOOKUP(H3,Credit!H:J,3,FALSE)<(J3*-1),"Additional Credit…  Research","No Credit Exists")))
```

I really would like to have a response to each formula, am I using the wrong functions or the wrong format?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repeating the VLOOKUP function multiple times you can use SIGN and CHOOSE in this scenario like this

`=CHOOSE(SIGN(VLOOKUP(H3,Credit!H:J,3,FALSE)+J3)+2,"Not enough Credit... research","Please Purge","Additional Credit… Research")`

If you add the VLOOKUP result to J3 you will get a negative number, zero or a positive number, SIGN function will return -1, 0 or 1 respectively for those and then adding 2 gives 1, 2 or 3 so we can use CHOOSE function to convert 1,2 or 3 to the relevant text value

That formula still gives #N/A error if H3 isn't found in Credit!H:H so to avoid that use IFERROR function (assumes Excel 207 or later), so final version becomes:

`=IFERROR(CHOOSE(SIGN(VLOOKUP(H3,Credit!H:J,3,FALSE)+J3)+2,"Not enough Credit... research","Please Purge","Additional Credit… Research"),"No credit exists")`

Answer (score 0):

perhaps

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(H3,Credit!H:H,0)),"No Credit Exists",IF(VLOOKUP(H3,Credit!H:J,3,FALSE)=(J3*-1),"Please Purge",IF(VLOOKUP(H3,Credit!H:J,3,FALSE)<(J3*-1),"Not enough Credit... research","Additional Credit… Research")))
```

the MATCH part looks for the value H3 in Credit!H:H and if it isn't there the ISNA handles the resulting error and returns "No credit exists"; the rest is basically just a tweak of the original formula

Comment: Care to elaborate on what this answer does that solves the problem?

Comment: I assumed the asker wanted the formula to return a response text for all three value options plus the no match option, which the ISNA part takes care of

Comment: What I meant was here we like answers that aren't just code - a little explanation helps teach the OP and visitors something and increases the quality of your answer.  You should add the explanation to your answer.